# What is the formal name for RTTI information, vtables etc. stored in a polymorphic type in C++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, language-lawyer, rtti, vtable

From [[intro.object](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object)] (emphasis mine):

> Some objects are polymorphic ([class.virtual]); the implementation generates **information associated with each such object that makes it possible to determine that object's type during program execution**.

Does this information (emphasized) have a name according to the spec or at least one used as a generally accepted convention?

That is, what should be the most formally correct way to refer to this *"information associated with each such object that makes it possible to determine that object's type during program execution"* other than by this full phrase?

Comment: I would think "Run-Time Type Information" is a fairly good description.

Comment: @AdrianMole I also thought about that, but RTTI alongside the vtable is like a static member, in this sense that object instances do not store it, but only a pointer to it. I think that the names for the non-static pointer and the static data could be different.

Comment: The C++ standard uses the term "type information" or "type information generated by the implementation"  - for example, in the introduction to the synopsis on `<typeinfo>`.   It doesn't use "runtime type information" or the acronym RTTI at all, except as a label on the relevant section heading (which is not normative text).    The standard does not describe virtual function tables or "vtables" at all - a vtable is one implementation approach for meeting requirements of the standard, but the standard neither mandates use of vtables nor specifies their structure.

Comment: "information associated with each such object that makes it possible to determine that object's type during program execution." seems pretty formal.  IAWESOTMIPTDTOTDPE for short I guess.

Comment: They're called "implementation details".